# How to scroll row items horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, horizontal-scrolling

as an exercise I'm trying to replicate a website like Netflix. 
If you see, in Netflix, every category has a row with videos that art distributed horizontally, with most of the videos located out of the screen "viewport" and you have to click an arrow button to scroll the rest of the content into view.

I was trying to replicate this with a mix between Bootstrap Cards as the video "placeholder" and flexbox to distribute the card equals horizontally. Then I though of maybe using something like a carrousel, but I haven't been able to find anything that works.

Any suggestions on how to do this without using javascript?

Thanks

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.contain {
 display: flex;
}

.card {
 width: 200px;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 border-radius: 0;
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 left: 5px;
}

.card-img-top {
 border-radius: 0;
}

.card-body {
 height: 100px;
 font-size: 50%;
 text-align: center;
}

.list-group-item {
 font-size: 50%;
 border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
 <div class="card" >
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5089/5342837785_b579b38145_o.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="card" >
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5089/5342837785_b579b38145_o.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="card" >
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5089/5342837785_b579b38145_o.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="card" >
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5089/5342837785_b579b38145_o.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="card" >
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5089/5342837785_b579b38145_o.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="card" >
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5089/5342837785_b579b38145_o.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="card" >
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5089/5342837785_b579b38145_o.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
     </ul>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I hope is helpful to you:: https://uxdesign.cc/creating-horizontal-scrolling-containers-the-right-way-css-grid-c256f64fc585

Answer (score 1):

Here, this should work.

```
    .contain {
      overflow: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      (your other CSS)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it kind of works, but it messes up all the content inside the card